# SQL lookup for pairs of value in single row only if they are present more then n times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 fields (Unique_ID, destination. dateofarrival).

I would like to check if two different unique IDs went to same destination for more than 4 times with a maximum delay of one day.

Any idea ?

Comment: is this going in the right direction? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436747/how-can-you-find-the-rows-with-equal-columns

Comment: can you please post some data and explain what exactly do you mean with 'same destination for more than 4 times...'?